# What is the best practice for handling async action errors in redux?

Tags: javascript, redux, es6-promise, redux-thunk

```
export const saveSomething = (thing = {}) => {
  dispatch({
    type: THING_SAVING,
  });

  return async function (dispatch) {
    try {
      await persistThing(thing);
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch({
        type: THING_SAVE_ERROR,
        error: e,
      });
      throw e;
    }

    dispatch({
      type: THING_SAVED,
      error: e,
    });
  }
}

handleSubmitClick(e) {
  dispatch(saveSomething({ name: e.target.value }))
    .catch(e => {
      // pass
    });
}
```

So, I'm probably overthinking this, but I'm trying to figure out the best practice here. When my async action has an error, even though I'm dispatching an error, it still feels right to throw it so the promise is rejected in case some components want to key on that. But, then that means in order to not have Create-React-App bomb on an unhandled promise rejection, I need to add this dummy catch when I dispatch the action, which IMHO is kinda ugly.

What's the best practice here? Not throw the error? Use the dummy catch? Something else?

Edit: The reason I need the dummy catch is because otherwise the app is bombing on me, at least in create-react-app:

[image]

(the error doesn't 100% match my pseudo code, but you get the point)

Comment: I would dispatch and throw. It is like you said, other functions could depend on it to resolve. The empty catch is pretty awkward, why do you even need it? So the error doesn't show in console?

Comment: @JohanP Without the empty catch create-react-app bombs on me (shows an error page). If it just silently showed in the console, I'd be fine with that.

Comment: Ah, I see. In your functions you dispatch when you encounter an error, why don't you have to dispatch when you get an error in `handleSubmitClick`?

Comment: @JohanP I'm not sure I understand the question. I dispatch a saveSomething action and that will dispatch an error which the reducer would use to change state. So, in this case, I have no use for a failed promise handler. But, having it resolve seems kind of wrong.

Comment: Why don't you need a `dispatch({
        type: THING_SAVE_ERROR,
        error: e,
      });` in your `.catch(e=>`?

Comment: The error is dispatched in the action creator... actually in the thunk returned by the action creator. Then the reducer handles the THING_SAVE_ERROR and updates the state and based off of the new state, the component knows there was an error.

Answer (score 1):

In my own projects I would try to manage all the error applications, probably with some generic action dispatcher that could be modified with proper error codes. But as for your example, you might not want to throw the error over, because you are using `await` in the method that can cause the error. So I would rewrite the code like this:

```
export const saveSomething = (thing = {}) => {
  dispatch({
    type: THING_SAVING,
  });

  return async function (dispatch) {
    try {
      await persistThing(thing);
      dispatch({
       type: THING_SAVED,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch({
        type: THING_SAVE_ERROR,
        error: e,
      });
    }
  }
}
```

If nothing happens and everything goes through the happy path, after the completion of the async call `persistThing`, the action dispatcher would get executed. And if `persistThing` generates an exception, the error action dispatcher would get executed.

Comment: That makes sense. It feels weird to me that in the case of an error, the saveSomething success handler is called as opposed to the fail or catch handler, but in this case, I'm not really using those anyway, so I guess my gripe is philosophical not practical.